# 451 Temporary local - PHP Mailer

Tags: email-server, sendmail, email-bounces

I am using phpmailer to do may emailing in the website, using SMTP auth. However recently i noticed that i gives me a error,

```
SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: info@xxx.com
```

Then i turned the debug variable to true in the mailer class, i got following as the output basically saying its a temporary problem and try again later, may i know what should i do to solve this problem ?

```
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220-servername ESMTP Exim 4.77 #2 Wed, 25 Jul 2012 08:59:03 +0530 "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220-servername ESMTP Exim 4.77 #2 Wed, 25 Jul 2012 08:59:03 +0530 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-servername Hello xxx.com [199.xxxx.185] "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "235 Authentication succeeded "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "235 Authentication succeeded "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 OK "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 OK "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "451 Temporary local problem - please try later "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "451 Temporary local problem - please try later "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:451 Temporary local problem - please try later
SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 451 Temporary local problem - please try later
SMTP Error: The following recipients failed: info@xxx.com
```

Comment: Do what the message says: `please try later`.

Comment: [This PDF](http://www.answersthatwork.com/Download_Area/ATW_Library/Networking/Network__3-SMTP_Server_Status_Codes_and_SMTP_Error_Codes.pdf) explains error 451 nicely

Answer (score 1):

You should really retry sending the e-mail if it says temporary problem, retry later.

Additionally, you could have a look at your Mailserver, maybe you are able to determine *why* the server sends this error message. (It's a server error message)

Answer (score 0):

I am making a lucky guess and I think that your /var filesystem (or where else your mail queues are stored) is full. Try issuing a `df -h` and see whether you have full filesystems or not.

Comment: not really.. system has plenty of free space...

Comment: Is the server on high load then? By high I mean load average higher than that set in the sendmail configuration in order for it to stop accepting mails.

Answer (score 0):

SMTP server software such as sendmail, postfix and exim is designed to handle large quantities of mail, try again in case of temporary problems, etc. Your script isn't, and shouldn't be, smart enough to manage all the intricacies of SMTP.

If it *is* your server, then you'll need to look at the server logs that it's generated to find out why it rejected the mail. If you're using a third party server, you'll need to contact the third party to find out what's going on with the mail server.

Comment: its a my own dedicated server, i am not a linux expert, i am not sure what to do.. i dont even know which smtp mail system it uses i.e sendmail, postfix, ... yes my websites sends out large email in bulk i.e 10,000+ per day sometimes... if its temp problem how do i know where is the problem ?

Comment: You first start by finding out what distribution you are running and whether you are running sendmail, postfix, exim or other.